# Swift - shorter way write the attached code?

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
class Device{
    var customerDeviceId:Int!
    var attribute:DeviceAttribute!
}

class DeviceAttribute{
    var customerDeviceId:Int!
}

class MainClass{
   var devices:[Device]!

   private func handleDeviceAttributes(_ attributes:[DeviceAttribute])  {
    for attribute in attributes {
        for device in devices {
            if device.customerDeviceId == attribute.customerDeviceId {
                device.attribute = attribute
            }
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

is there any shorter way to write it? maybe even skip the nested for loops?

Comment: show DeviceAttribute  &  customerDevices objects or what are you trying to do, like the logic of it because its not so clear to me.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson assuming device is a `class` and the `deviceAttribute` property is mutable, it should compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a functional approach.

```
customerDevices.forEach { device in
    device.deviceAttribute = attributes.last(where: { $0.customerDeviceId == device.customerDeviceId })
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this assumes there's only one attribute with a matching `customerDeviceId`. On the other hand, OP's code doesn't make such assumption and assigns the _last_ matching object.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you're right, according to the original code it's better to use the `last`function

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the work

```
customerDevices.forEach { (customerDevice) in
        customerDevice.deviceAttribute = attributes.compactMap({ (attribute) -> DeviceAttribute? in
            return attribute.customerDeviceId == customerDevice.customerDeviceId ? attribute : nil
        }).first
    }
```